# Android Thread keep getting suspended(exception InflateException))

Tags: android, xml

I am a beginner in android apps development and I'm doing this simple tutorial that make an app to add product name, price and details, after fixing some errors here and there, create products codes works in adding new products, but viewing the products information I keep getting error message : 'unfortunately app has stopped working'. I am using Eclipse Luna IDE.

In the debug page, it is shown like this :

> Thread [<1> main] (Suspended(exception InflateException))

This is the java code :

AllProductsActivity.java

```
package com.example.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AllProductsActivity extends ListActivity {

    //Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    //Creating JSON parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

    //url to get all products list
    private static String url_all_products = "http://api.kerjaapa.com/android_connect/get_all_products.php";

    //JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";

    //products JSONArray
    JSONArray products = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.all_products);

        //Hashmap for ListView
        productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        //Loading products in background thread
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();

        //Get listview
        ListView lv = getListView();

        //on selecting single product
        //launching Edit Product Screen
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                //getting values from selected ListItem
                String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                    .toString();

                //Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    EditProductActivity.class);
                //sending pid to next activity
                in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);
                //starting new activity and expecting some response back
                startActivityForResult(in, 100);
            }
        });
    }

    //Response from Edit Product Activity
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        //if result code 100
        if (resultCode == 100) {
            //if result code 100 is received
            //means user edited/deleted product
            //reload this screen again
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    //Background Async task to load all products by making http request
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        //Before starting background thread show progress dialog
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllProductsActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        //getting all products from url
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            //Building parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            //getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

            //Check your log cat for JSON response
            Log.d("All Products : ", json.toString());

            try {
                //checking for success tag
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    //products found
                    //getting array of products
                    products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                    //looping through all products
                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                        //Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                        //creating new Hashmap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        //adding each child node to Hashmap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                        //adding hashlist to arraylist
                        productsList.add(map);

                    }
                } else {
                    //no products found
                    //launch add new product activity
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            NewProductActivity.class);
                    //closing all previous activity
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        //after completing background task dismiss the progress dialog
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            //dismiss dialog after getting products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            //updating UI from background thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    //updating parsed JSON data into listview
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            AllProductsActivity.this, productsList,
                            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                    TAG_NAME},
                            new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });
                    //updating listView
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });
        }

    }

}
```

And here is for the layout xml file :

all_products.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- Main ListView
         Always give id value as list(@android:id/list)
    -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- Product id (pid) - will be HIDDEN - used to pass to other activity -->
    <Textview
        android:id="@+id/pid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <!-- Name Label -->
    <Textview
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I really don't know where to start debugging and look for mistakes, tried using the log cat, but couldn't get anything useful to show the mistakes. Thought it might be the source problem, I have installed the latest source android SDK and attach it to the project, but under debug, there are still some file with 'source not found', these files are :

> NativeStart.main(String[])line:not available[native method]
>
> ViewRoot.handleMessage(Message)line:1727
>
> ViewRoot.performTraversals()line:801

The stack under Thread[<1> main] are :

> PhoneLayoutInflater(LayoutInflater).inflate(int, ViewGroup, boolean) line: 322
>   SimpleAdapter.createViewFromResource(int, View, ViewGroup, int) line: 121 
>   SimpleAdapter.getView(int, View, ViewGroup) line: 114 
>   ListView(AbsListView).obtainView(int, boolean[]) line: 1315
>   ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(int, int, int, int, int) line: 1198
>   ListView.onMeasure(int, int) line: 1109
>   ListView(View).measure(int, int) line: 8171
>   LinearLayout(ViewGroup).measureChildWithMargins(View, int, int, int, int) line: 3132
>   LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(View, int, int, int, int, int) line: 1012
>   LinearLayout.measureVertical(int, int) line: 381
>   LinearLayout.onMeasure(int, int) line: 304
>   LinearLayout(View).measure(int, int) line: 8171
>   FrameLayout(ViewGroup).measureChildWithMargins(View, int, int, int, int) line: 3132
>   FrameLayout.onMeasure(int, int) line: 245 
>   FrameLayout(View).measure(int, int) line: 8171
>   LinearLayout.measureVertical(int, int) line: 526
>   LinearLayout.onMeasure(int, int) line: 304
>   LinearLayout(View).measure(int, int) line: 8171
>   PhoneWindow$DecorView(ViewGroup).measureChildWithMargins(View, int, int, int, int) line: 3132 
>   PhoneWindow$DecorView(FrameLayout).onMeasure(int, int) line: 245
>   PhoneWindow$DecorView(View).measure(int, int) line: 8171
>   ViewRoot.performTraversals() line: 801
>   ViewRoot.handleMessage(Message) line: 1727
>   ViewRoot(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99
>   Looper.loop() line: 123
>   ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4627
>   Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: > not available [native method]
>   Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 521
>   ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 868
>   ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 626
>   NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]

Could someone help me elaborate why does these stack appear, while I think there is nothing wrong for most of them, as the source file are there (only the three files are showing 'source not found'..

I also notice that Eclipse is giving warning that NameValuePair is deprecated, could it be the problem ? and also if it is, what is the solution, I have been researching anywhere and I found to use openConnection(), but I dont'know how to use it, any guide ?

Thx again.

Comment: It would help a lot if you could give the full stack trace of the issue you are seeing and indicate the line it indicates (from line number).

Comment: there you go, I added the stack, its a long list, and I think most of them shouldn't have a problem cause the source files are attached correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making the "V" in "Textview" capital in the two instances in `list_item.xml` (so it will read `TextView` instead). I think the problem has to do with it not being able to inflate a those, since that's not the class name.

Comment: Wow, you are a genius !!! oh my god, been searching for bugs since morning, turns out only capital letters problem. Thank you so much.

Comment: Why on earth was this not a compile time error. Google really messed up with Android studio

Comment: To be fair, he was using Eclipse, not AS. But yeah, this really should be caught by Lint/compilation. I think AS actually would have done a better job of highlighting this particular issue.